# how to use Image upload in ckeditor using vue-ckeditor?

Tags: vue.js, ckeditor4.x, ckeditor5

i am using ckeditor. image button is shown in toolbar but when i click and upload image. uploaded images is not shown in the editor.

```
  <ckeditor :editor="editor" v-model="form.title" :config="editorConfig"></ckeditor>
```

[image]

image button there in toolbar but unable to upload image.

You can also see in below link image:
https://codepen.io/ckeditor/details/EJBYop

Comment: What are the errors in the console?

Comment: no errors in console but uploaded image just not shown in the content area

Answer (score 2):

you have to add custom upload adapter if you don't want to import CKEditor from source and do not want to change in webpack configuration. 
i.e. if you want to use [base64adapter](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/image-upload/base64-upload-adapter.html) you can do something like

```
export default class UploadAdapter
{
    constructor (loader)
    {
        // The file loader instance to use during the upload.
        this.loader = loader;
    }

    // Starts the upload process.
    upload ()
    {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        {
            const reader = new window.FileReader();

            reader.addEventListener('load', () =>
            {
                resolve({'default': reader.result});
            });

            reader.addEventListener('error', err =>
            {
                reject(err);
            });

            reader.addEventListener('abort', () =>
            {
                reject();
            });

            this.loader.file.then(file =>
            {
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            });
        });
    }

    // Aborts the upload process.
    abort ()
    {
         //
    }
}

export const uploader = function (editor)
{
    editor.plugins.get('FileRepository').createUploadAdapter = (loader) =>
        new UploadAdapter(loader);
};
```

and in ckeditor editor config

```
   'editorConfig': {'extraPlugins': [uploader]}
```